# How to delete rows using group_by conditionals. R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My dataset looks like this

```
Year     id      APV      APS 
2012     A        Y        N
2013     A        NA       NA
2014     A        NA       NA
2015     A        NA       NA
2016     A        NA       NA
2017     A        NA       NA
2018     A        NA       NA
2019     A        NA       NA

2012     B        Y        N
2013     B        Y        N
2014     B        NA       NA
2015     B        NA       NA
2016     B        NA       NA
2017     B        NA       NA
2018     B        NA       NA
2019     B        NA       NA

2012     C        Y        Y
2013     C        Y        Y
2014     C        Y        Y
2015     C        Y        Y
2016     C        Y        Y
2017     C        Y        Y
2018     C        Y        Y
2019     C        Y        Y
.        .        .        .
.        .        .        .
.        .        .        .
```

How can I delete the A and B observations? (That have APV **and** APS as `NA` on 2014 **&** 2015 **&** 2016 **&** 2017 **&** 2018 **&** 2019)

Comment: What is the logic to delete an `id` ? Do you want to delete an id if there is `NA` in `APV` and `APS` in any of the year?

Comment: You could use [`dplyr::filter()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html).

Comment: @RonakShah I want to delete that category (id), conditional in that the APS or APV from 2014 to 2019 is NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete an `id` if it has all the values as `NA` in `APV` and `APS` column between 2014 and 2019.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!all(is.na(APV[between(Year, 2014, 2019)]) & 
              is.na(APS[between(Year, 2014, 2019)]))) %>%
  ungroup

#   Year id    APV   APS  
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1  2012 C     Y     Y    
#2  2013 C     Y     Y    
#3  2014 C     Y     Y    
#4  2015 C     Y     Y    
#5  2016 C     Y     Y    
#6  2017 C     Y     Y    
#7  2018 C     Y     Y    
#8  2019 C     Y     Y
```